# find maximum of $|e^{-z^2}|$ for $|z|\geq5$ and $0\leq Arg(z)\leq\pi/8$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Goal: find maximum of $m=|e^{-z^2}|$ for $|z|\geq5$ and $0\leq Arg(z)\leq\pi/8$

my understanding is after expanding with $z = re^{i\theta}, m=e^{-r^2cos\theta}$,$cos\theta>0\therefore argmax_r\ m=0$. But the given answer says the maximum is $e^{-25/\sqrt{2}}$ what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|e^{-z^{2}}|=e^{-r^{2} \cos (2 \theta)}$ where $z=re^{i\theta}$. The minimum vaue of $\cos (2 \theta)$ for $ 0 \leq \theta \leq \frac {\pi} 8$ is $\cos (\frac {\pi} 4)=\frac  1 {\sqrt 2}$ since $\cos$ is decreasing in $[0,\frac {\pi} 2]$.   Hence $|e^{-z^{2}}| \leq e^{-25 /\sqrt 2}$ and this value is attained when  $z=5e^{i\frac {\pi} 8}$.